# php mysqli query won't work

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm trying to increase the value in the table by one but I don't really know mysql and I don't know whats wrong. It seems to go through no problem but when I check the database the number hasn't changed. Thanks in advance! :)

```
    $con = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
} else {
    echo "it works!";
}

switch ($_POST['found']) {
    case "facebook":
        mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `found` SET `number` = 'number + 1' WHERE `id` = 'Facebook'");


        break;
```

Comment: this is erroring out `= 'number + 1'` and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php  would have told you about it.

Comment: Hi sorry I'm only learning mysqli, how do i increment it by one so that is does error out? thanks a mill!

Comment: just remove the quotes around that and you'll be good to go ;-)

Comment: You have to remove the quotes around number+1, and i would work. When you are using a column name in your query, you shouldn't wrap it with quotes

Comment: you are setting `number` to a string, `number + 1`, because of the quotes.

Comment: *You're welcome* ;-) easy huh?

Comment: its things like these that i just would have never gotten!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
 case "facebook":
    mysqli_query($con,"UPDATE `found` SET number = number + 1 WHERE `id` = 'Facebook'") or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!